# Not receiving FCM notifications in a PWA in energy saving mode

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I'm struggling to find any details about PWA and power / energy saving mode in general.  The exact problem is I am not receiving Firebase Cloud Messages FCM in my PWA running on Chrome on Android in energy saving mode and I'm not really sure where to start looking for the answer.